# Angular UI Router redirecting to default page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, routes

I have a modular application where i have routes split into multiple files.

So my system is.

```
Top
--Main.Module.js
--Main.Routes.js
--Main.Controllers.js
--Main.html
--user (folder)
----User.Module.js
----User.Routes.js
----User.Controllers.js
```

And in the user folder I have a login folder with a Login.html and a register folder with a Register.html

The main module file looks like this

```
angular.module('Main', ['ionic', 'Main.Routes', 'Main.Controllers', "User"])

  .run(function($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

      }
      if (window.StatusBar) {
        // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
        StatusBar.styleDefault();
      }
    });
  });
```

The main route file contains

```
angular.module('Main.Routes', [])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

    .state('Loader', {
      url: '/',
      templateUrl: '/views/Main.html',
      controller: 'MainController'
    });

   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
});
```

And the Main.Module.js injects these two things as well as the User module which js file looks like this

```
angular.module('User', ['User.Controllers', 'User.Services', 'User.Routes']);
```

The user routes file has the routes for the login page and the register page

```
angular.module('User.Routes', [])

.config(function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider

    .state('Login', {
      url: '/user/login',
      templateUrl: 'views/user/login/Login.html',
      controller: 'LoginController'
    })

    .state('Register', {
      url: '/user/register',
      templateUrl: 'views/user/register/Register.html'

    });



  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback


});
```

And when I do $state.go("Login") from the main controller it takes me to the login page without any issue. But I have a register button on the login page which is associated with this block of code

```
//Move user to the register page
  $scope.registerClick = function(){
    $state.go("Register");
  }
```

Which redirects me to the register page for around half a second then immediately kick it back over to the main html page. So my question is i need to know why the state isnt staying with the register page and is moving immediately to the main.html page. The register page is part of the page history stack because i can go "back" to it with either the hardware back button or pressing back on chrome during testing. I tried moving the routes back to the main route file and not injecting the user routes but it produced the same results.

==============EDIT=============
Once the application loads, if i change the page it goes to after the main page to the register page and add a link back to the login page this behavior does not occur. I'm just confused on whats different.

Comment: do a `console.log($state.href("Register"))` and tell us what you get?

Comment: #/user/register when done from the RegisterController

Comment: And if i go to that url directly from the address bar i dont have an issue. It's just when i try to redirect it from the login page does it have this problem

Comment: If you can capture `$stateChangeError` or other relevant events and see if you have any error there

Comment: Unless im doing it wrong it's not throwing any errors. I added $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError',
      function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error){ e.preventDefault(); console.log(error) }); and nothing showed up. The route even loads the controller because itll run any js that I have in there before returning back to the either the login page or the home page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see what I did wrong. In the location where I had my button that was supposed to take me to the register page alongside the ng-click directive i also had a href directive set to #. Thank you all for your input though.

The offending line

```
<a href="#" ng-click="registerClick()" class="button button-light  button-block button-clear ">Create an account</a>
```

What it should have been

```
<a href="#" ng-click="registerClick()" class="button button-light  button-block button-clear ">Create an account</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

set an `otherwise`

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/defaultpage');
        .state('login', {
                    url: '/login',
                    templateUrl: 'templates/template.html',
                    controller: 'Ctrl'
                })
        .otherstates etc....

        });
```

Comment: I had tried this previously. It did not solve my issue.